# How do I stop Outlook 2016+ from nagging to change to the new “look”?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I don't like the new look, and I don't want to change over to it. So, I click the "Not Now" button, but every so often, up pops a reminder. How can I get rid of the notification, permanently (at least until the next install)?

Comment: Should disappear, if you click the change button to change to it, then simply switch back.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the new look in your question?   I have Office 2016 on newest Windows 10 20H2 and also Insider Windows (newer than newest) and Office (Outlook) does not appear to have changed much in the last 4 or 5 months.

Comment: @LPChip write it as an answer and I'll take it. This works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a developer creates a "feature" and advertises to switch to it, the last thing the developer wants, is keep nagging the user that already clicked the button they want to click. Its a strange logic, but clicking on the x or not now is not the same as yes and then switching back.

Each button has logic behind it, and if you click the Try Now button, one of the things most developers will do is ensure that popup never comes back. Microsoft is one of those that does it right. They will nag you to try out features, but if you tried it and then switch back, they should not bother you with it again.

So the easiest solution is going to be, click the button to switch to it, then simply switch back to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this tip in my Outlook, but I have seen another tip(download outlook for android) and I disable it succesfully via uncheck the privacy option in Outlook(File>Options>Trust center settings>Privacy option), maybe you could also try it.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but interesting nonetheless. I wasn't aware of this option. It's amazing how much cruft there is in these settings.